# Git bash - Changes not staged for commit

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I'd wanted to merge two branches to master, and then, continue to develop project, but unfortunately, I cannot make any commit/push. I have three branches:

```
master
daily_front
daily_back
```

How I'm suppose to solve that error?

```
$ git commit -m "merging daily_front with master"
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
modified:   MyProject(modified content)

no changes added to commit
```

Here's what do I do before:

1 - merge master with daily_front

2 - add .

3 - tried to commit, as you can see above.

I'm totally newbie in git, please for some "soft" explanation.

Comment: Have you merged the branch already? And then made changes afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to merge branch `daily_front` to `master` and end up with a custom commit, you can run the following command from `master`:

```
$ git merge daily_front --no-ff -m "merging daily_front with master"
```

this will create a merge commit with the desired message.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error. When you simply say `git merge`, that *is* a commit. Therefore, right after a merge, you cannot do a commit; there is nothing to commit. You've already *done* the commit when you said `git merge`. Your merge was successful and you should go back to whatever you were doing previously.